# maintaining graphs without cycles or diamonds

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I want to maintain a directed graph in hibernate/sql (ie: a simple many-to-many self association) that does not have cycles or diamonds.

By "no diamonds", I mean there is no more than one "path" from any node to any other node. I believe that these two rules mean that every node may be treated as the root of two trees - one going one way, one the other.

Is there a well-known algorithm for this? The question boils down to: "given that the graph is currently well-formed, if I were to put an arc between A and B, will this create a loop or a diamond"?

Comment: It seems like this is equivalent to asking if nodes A and B have any common ancestors.

Comment: Yes. The difficulty is that A and B both have a tree of ancestors: it's not a matter of running up the "child of" chain as it is in a simple tree.

Comment: come to think of it - the detection of loops is also more complicated than in a simple tree graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll only be adding edges and not removing them, think you could solve this by making your graph also have [disjoint set semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). When creating a new edge, you'd first check that the two nodes are not already part of the same set. If they were not, you'd create the link and perform a union on the sets.

Here's some Python code, which I hope will be close enough to pseudocode to be understandable even if you don't know Python.

```
class Node:
    # constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.setParent = None
        self.graphParents = []
        self.graphChildren = []

    # disjoint set operations
    def getSetRoot(self):
        if self.setParent == None:
            return self
        else:
            self.setParent = self.setParent.getSetRoot()
            return self.setParent

    def joinSet(self, other):
        other.getSetRoot().setParent = self.getSetRoot()

    # graph operation
    def addChild(self, child):
        if self.getSetRoot() == child.getSetRoot():
            raise ValueError("Cannot add child!")
        else:
            self.graphChildren.append(child)
            child.graphParents.append(self)
            self.joinSet(child)
```

As I mentioned, this only works if you never remove any edges. Doing so would require rebuilding the disjoint sets for the newly separated graph segments, which could be very slow. It might still be reasonable to go this route if you will remove edges only very rarely (many times less often than you make additions).